# write blob to file system in phonegap or cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Cordova@4.3.0

On Android using fileWriter.write(blob) does not work for me.

The blob can be anything e.g. a pdf, a text file etc

I simply get a 2 byte file on the Android file system no matter what type of file I have in the blob.

Has anyone successfully wrote a blob to the local file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a tough one to find.

The Blob I was passing in was created using the Blob constructor in an iFrame.

The phonegap javascript is running in the main window of the browser. Hence the test in FileWriter.write to check if the data passed in is a blob failed in my case since my Blob (created in an iFrame) was not an instanceof Blob (in the window)

I had to construct a new window.parent.Blob() instead and all was fine.